# Error during turtlebot launch in ROS

Tags: ros

When I run 
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch

I am getting this error:-

```
> from defusedxml.xmlrpc import monkey_patch ImportError: No module
> named defusedxml.xmlrpc while processing
> /opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlebot_gazebo/launch/includes/kobuki.launch.xml:
> Invalid tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]:
> command [/opt/ros/kinetic/share/xacro/xacro.py
> '/opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlebot_description/robots/kobuki_hexagons_asus_xtion_pro.urdf.xacro']
> returned with code [1].

Param xml is param command="$(arg urdf_file)" name="robot_description"/>
Param xml is The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since It was related import module I solved using

```
pip install defusedxml
```